# Laraver JWT key, Method issue() does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I want to implement codecast JWT key to Laravel
https://github.com/codecasts/laravel-jwt

I follow the instructions step by step, but throw Exception
`Method issue() does not exist.`
Any Idea what is wrong?

My code:

```
function login(Guard $auth){
        $user2 = User::find(1);
        $auth->login($user2);
        $token = $auth->issue();
        return $token;
    }
```

Comment: have you done php artisan jwt:generate? and placed its content on the .env file

Comment: yes, of corse..

Comment: That package doesnt look like a well maintained one. `tymondesigns/jwt-auth` is the real deal